# Creating custom pattern for input element

Tags: html

Sometimes I see input elements that have their own custom pattern, for example, a zip code input element always brings a `-` automatically after the user has typed 4 characters. Or an input element for hours and minutes brings a `:` after the user has input the first 2 characters.

Is this a JavaScript or a HTML function?

What tags should I search to learn this?

Comment: search for "js input mask" :)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5/JavaScript Input Mask or masked textbox is a control that provides an easy and reliable way to collect user input based on a standard mask. It allows you to capture phone numbers, date values, credit card numbers, and other standard format values.

You can learn about it in:
https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/